# Best-practise: lazy-loading or getting ALL properties

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I got a question when it comes to lazy-loading. For this, I use LinQ to NHibernate but I assume it will also apply to other LINQ to XX methodologies.

Imagine a **User** tabel with column:

ID
Name
Address
Password (for this example: plain, not hashed)

And imagine a **Role** table:

ID
Name

And of course, there's the many-to-many table **UserRole** (with additional info like CreateDate).

When you only want to get the **names** of the **roles** of a specific **user** you can do this via **eager-loading** with the following query:

```
var roles = session.Query<User>().FetchMany(u => u.UserRoles)
                                .ThenFetch(ur => ur.Role)
                                .Single(u => u.Id == userId)
                                .UserRoles.Select(ug => new { ug.Role.Name } );
```

**Lazy-loading**:

```
var roles = session.Query<User>().Single(u => u.Id == userId)
                                .UserRoles.Select(ug => new { ug.Role.Name } );
```

The advantages of eager-loading: Instead of 2 or 3 calls to the database each time you only have 1 call
The disadvantage of eager-loading: even though you say you ONLY want the Name returned, the query itself will result in getting ALL the properties of all included tables from the database (including sensitive information like in our example passwords) and once inside your code it will filter the name only.

Can anyone give some advice on which of these 2 are best-practise? Or is there any other way of eager-loading without loading all the properties. Please no advice on using stored procedures.

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

As to whether or not to use lazy-loading or eager-loading. That really depends on what your users are going to do more often. If your users end up touching your mapping reference over 50% (*I am not sure on what a good percentage is, but let's go with this) of the time, then you should go with eager loading. Otherwise, you should use lazy-loading. The percentage should probably vary depending on the cost that is incurred by the loads.

However, I would say to go with the default behavior of most ORM's (lazy-loading) unless you actually have a problem. Stick with the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) first motto. :)

That is just my two cents at least :)

Comment: I understand your vision. But what about security? How dangerous is it if - take for example bank account numbers - are sent out of the database to a client while the client actually doesn't need it? The data transfer between the database and a client is not secured or is it?